# Select box showing db value not allowing update

Tags: php, html

This code finally worked to display a previous selection $MedIDinDB in a lookup table based select box as desired, but it will not allow a new selection to change the control's selected value for posting an update as needed. How do I do both?

```
<select name="MedSelect" value="<?php 

$sql = "SELECT MedID, MedName FROM Meds ORDER BY Rank ASC";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
if($query) {
    $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($row as $value){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['MedID']; ?>"<?php if ($value['MedID'] == $MedIDinDB) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $value['MedName']; ?> 
        </option>
<?php }} ?>

</select>
```

Comment: first I would clean up the select tag. You need to end the select BEFORE value and remove value altogether: so it would be <select name="MedSelect"><?php

Comment: that improvement didn't work, is my mistake elsewhere?

Comment: Confused to what you are really asking. Thought at first it was a JavaScript, onchange type question... Share the actual output perhaps? Check logs for errors... standard debugging. You tell us what is wrong.

Comment: This control worked to update the db when there was not any selection of the options until the current session.  When I succeeded in getting it to display a previous session's selection, I lost the form's ability to update the db. I assumed that the controls selected value was not being allowed to change from the $MedIDinDB value. I want the select box to show the db value and also for posting to update a users change to a different selection.

Answer (score 1):

Select in HTML doesn't have `value=` attribute.
You can keep your code cleaner by concatenating instead of escaping PHP code:

```
<select name="MedSelect">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT MedID, MedName FROM Meds ORDER BY Rank ASC";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $value) {
    $selected = $value['MedID'] == $MedIDinDB ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="'. $value['MedID'] .'" '. $selected .'>'. $value['MedName'] .'</option>';
} 
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @imvain2 is saying that looks improperly formatted. I see an answer has been supplied so I won't explain again but thought I'd share an example of how you can format HTML/PHP spaghetti better.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT MedID, MedName FROM Meds ORDER BY Rank ASC";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<select name="MedSelect">
    <?php if(!empty($rows)): ?>
        <?php foreach($row as $value): ?>        
            <option value="<?= $value['MedID'] ?>" <?= ($value['MedID'] == $MedIDinDB) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>><?= $value['MedName'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```